# Algorithm for searching place to add a circle to existing set on the plane

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Given the rectangle of some arbitrary size `a * b` I am placing randomly circles of diameter `1`, one by one, without overlapping.

But when rectangle is fairly covered, how can I check whether there is a place for one more circle, or not? Could some kind of triangulation help me?

Comment: Your `one by one` isn't enough to describe how you're placing your circles.

Comment: Related question (although not exact) - [How many circles of a given radius can be packed into a given rectangular box?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701/how-many-circles-of-a-given-radius-can-be-packed-into-a-given-rectangular-box)

Comment: I meant to describe process of placing them **sequentially** and **at random** which differs the task from dense packing (as in proposed related question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a specialist in geometric algorithms, but it seems to me that you could compute the Voronoi diagram (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of the center of the circles. Then the maximal distance from the centers is reached at one the vertex of the diagram. Therefore if all those vertex are of distance less than 2 then there isn't any place left for a new one.

Comment: Hm... Since Voronoy Diagram is the inversion of Delaunay triangulation - I suppose it is the approach which loomed to me, so I think it is correct idea... Thanks!